# Server distributing/sharing a symmetric key to one or more clients via an established secure connection?

Tags: symmetric, key-exchange

I have a server and a client device that share two separate data channels that each need to have authentication and encryption protections.

When a connection is made over data channel 1, it is secured using TLS where all data after handshaking is authenticated and encrypted using a single session key via AES-CCM.

Data channel 2 is completely separate one-way communication from server to client that is also to be authenticated and encrypted via AES-CCM. I would like to have the server generate the 2nd key and distribute it over the secure channel 1 connection.  Are there any defined protocols on how to do the distribution/sharing aspect of this?  Can I send the generated channel 2 key via the channel 1 connection without additional key wrapping or other mitigations?

I've seen some related posts but many were relatively old and it wasn't clear to me whether they were asking about the same thing I am.

Comment: Could you also write down the posts that you read? When you say mitigation, you simply assume that there are problems there. There is nothing wrong with sending the key over the first channel. The logic is simple. If there is a problem of sending data over the first channel then the TLS is not securing the channel 1.

Comment: kelalaka, your point about there being nothing wrong with sending it over the first channel (that is secured) was my assumption, but I was thinking there may be some specification or overall guidance on how distribute/share keys over a secure channel that i wasn't aware of...it sounds like it's perfectly acceptable to send the key for the 2nd channel over the 1st channel without any extra controls (e.g. it doesn't need to be wrapped with KEK before being sent over the 1st channel)